Error loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory



I want to transfer a software written in 2016 that is actively running on Raspberry 2 to Raspberry 5. In this migration process, I copied all the files to RP5. However, when I run it on RP5, my other codes do not work because I cannot run my file named 'gateway', even though I take a screenshot via localhost. This gateway file is an executable file. As seen in the photo below, the necessary libraries for the gateway have been written.
The problem I am currently experiencing is that I want to install the library named libboost_system.so.1.55.0 on my RP5. As you can see in the pictures, I installed it, but I still get the same library error when I try to run the gateway folder. Did I make a mistake in the installation part? Am I making a location path mistake? Can you help me with this? What path should I follow?
pi@raspberrypi:~/eos-gateway $ file gateway
gateway: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=5d922572a7f8a45905671e08c5221ec4a1f9ee4f, with debug_info, not stripped
pi@raspberrypi:~/eos-gateway $ readelf -d gateway

Dynamic section at offset 0x1af188 contains 35 entries:
  Tag        Type                          Name/Value
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libcaf_io.so.0.14.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libcaf_core.so.0.14.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [librf24-bcm.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libmysqlcppconn.so.7]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libboost_system.so.1.55.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libcrypto.so.1.0.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x0000000f (RPATH)                      Library rpath: [/usr/local/lib]
 0x0000000c (INIT)                       0x24358
 0x0000000d (FINI)                       0x178d80
 0x00000019 (INIT_ARRAY)                 0x1cf12c
 0x0000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)               84 (bytes)
 0x0000001a (FINI_ARRAY)                 0x1cf180
 0x0000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)               4 (bytes)
 0x6ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)                   0x10194
 0x00000005 (STRTAB)                     0x14f64
 0x00000006 (SYMTAB)                     0x11ac4
 0x0000000a (STRSZ)                      57104 (bytes)
 0x0000000b (SYMENT)                     16 (bytes)
 0x00000015 (DEBUG)                      0x0
 0x00000003 (PLTGOT)                     0x1cf2c8
 0x00000002 (PLTRELSZ)                   2880 (bytes)
 0x00000014 (PLTREL)                     REL
 0x00000017 (JMPREL)                     0x23818
 0x00000011 (REL)                        0x236b8
 0x00000012 (RELSZ)                      352 (bytes)
 0x00000013 (RELENT)                     8 (bytes)
 0x6ffffffe (VERNEED)                    0x23508
 0x6fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)                 6
 0x6ffffff0 (VERSYM)                     0x22e74
 0x00000000 (NULL)                       0x0
pi@raspberrypi:~/eos-gateway $ sudo ./gateway
./gateway: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_system.so.1.55.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
pi@raspberrypi:~/eos-gateway $

I installed the library with sudo apt-get install libboost1.55*. With this installation, I also installed it in the usr/local/lib location. But I still get the libboost1.55 error. I think I made a location error or an installation error, but I don't know how to check.


I want to transfer a software written in 2016 that is actively running on Raspberry 2 to Raspberry 5. In this migration process, I copied all the files to RP5.

That won't work that way; as you notice you need the exact ABI-compatible versions of your dependencies in 32 bit (your OS is probably/hopefully 64 bit on your RPi5, or you're losing access to half your RAM and a lot of performance), and there's more than libboost-system, but also libcrypto and libmysqlcppcon.
You did not install libboost-system; you just copied the source tarball somewhere, and unpacked it. That's not an ABI-compatible build of boost.

I installed the library with sudo apt-get install libboost1.55*.

That should have installed nothing; current debian doesn't ship boost 1.55.
What you need to achieve is a situation where the libraries your "gateway" software uses are the libraries that your operating system brings.
That can either be done via running your "old" debian e.g. in a container and figuring out which parts of your system you need to expose to that container, or, and that seems indicated, considering the libraries you're linking against, you really need to re-build your software to use your modern libraries. Note that the fact that one of the libraries you link against has -bcm in its name might mean you need a new version of that library anyways, since that's typically short for "broadcom", which is the supplier of the CPU on your RPi, and that has changed quite a bit since your old RPi.
In this case, the rebuild is probably easier: librf24-bcm, which your gateway uses, is a GPL2 library, meaning that wherever you have gateway from, you also should have access to the source code and all scripts necessary to rebuild that software. I don't know how you built that gateway software back then, but I bet that information is still somewhere on your old RPi image!
